# Look up salary information by name from a list

Tags: python

I'm writing some python code that works out a person's total pay.

I am able to do this by getting the user to input their pay, however I would like them just to be able to enter their name and then the name is searched in position 0 of a list (Eg. 0,1 0,2 0,2 etc).

I have tried using a tuple but it is not callable and the dictionary and list would not work for me either.

```
counter = 0
valid = 0
employeelist = [["thomas","2","500"], ["jake","1","750"]]
while True:
  while True:
    try:
      name = str(input("Name:"))
    except ValueError:
      print("Error")
      continue
    else:
      break
  while True:
    if name == employeelist[counter,0]:
      print(employeelist[counter])
      break
      valid = 1
    elif counter = 3:
      print("invalid name")
      break
    else:
      counter = counter + 1
  if valid == 1:
    break
months = employeelist[counter,1]
pay = employeelist[counter,1]
totalpay = int(months) * int(pay)
```

Edit:

I do no longer have the code with the dictionary, however I just edited the code from [counter,1] and [0,1] to [counter][1] and is working fine thank you :D

Comment: You should read [ask] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Try `if name == employeelist[counter][0]:` instead of `if name == employeelist[counter,0]:`. But I agree with the comment below me, the dictionary method would be the best starting point to get fixed for this kind of task.

Comment: _" the dictionary and list would not work for me either."_ A dictionary is almost certainly the correct approach here. Please share the code where you tried using a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is for your inner loop

```
employeelist = [["thomas","2","500"], ["jake","1","750"]]
name = ""
while True:
    try:
        name = input("Name:")
        break
    except:
        print "Error"
position = -1
for i, element in enumerate(employeelist):
    if element[0] == name: 
        position = i
        break
if position == -1:
    print "Invalid Name"
else:
    totalpay = int(employeelist[position][1]) * int(employeelist[position][2])
```

Comment: I made a typo with the `enumerate` line. What error are you getting?

Comment: you don't close quotes on the `name = input("Name: )` line

Answer (score 0):

Your code have multiple bugs. First, `valid=1`, is set after breaking the loop -meaning `valid=1`,is never set. You also are checking `elif counter = 3` this way, you should rather use two equality signs, like this: `elif counter == 3`

The error you are getting, that list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple, you are having because you are accessing a multidimensional array the wrong way. Instead of `name == employeelist[counter, 0]`, it should be `name == employeelist[counter][0]`.

Your way of iterating through the array is possible, but its rather simpler using a for loop.

Try this way.

```
for employees in employeelist:
     if name == employees[0]:
          print(employee)
          valid = 1
          break
```

If it iterated through the hole employeelist, without the `if`-block running, `valid = 1`, would never been set.

Working code:

```
counter = 0 
valid = 0 
employeelist = [["thomas","2","500"], ["jake","1","750"]]

while True:
  while True:
    try:
      name = str(input("Name: "))
    except ValueError:
      print("Error")
      continue
    else:
      break

  for employees in employeelist:
    if name == employees[0]:
      print(employees)
      valid = 1
      break

  if valid == 1:
    break

months = employeelist[counter][1]
pay = employeelist[counter][2]
totalpay = int(months) * int(pay)
print(totalpay)
```

Comment: Nice answer. My tiniest issue with it is that I'd rename `employees` with `employee` (singular) since the plural makes me think you're accessing an inner list.

Comment: Well, change it if you want. I agree with you that it makes more sense with employee, rather than employees, beacuse we're iterating through each employee one by one.